# Astyanax cql3 COUNT query returning ROWS not NUMBER

Tags: java, cassandra, cql3, astyanax

According to the example page of Astyanax:

https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki/Cql-and-cql3

When you run a `COUNT` query, the `result` returns a "number", so you can query that with:

```
try {
    OperationResult<CqlResult<String, String>> result
        = keyspace.prepareQuery(CF_STANDARD1)
            .withCql("SELECT count(*) FROM Standard1 where KEY='A';")
            .execute();

    System.out.println("CQL Count: " + result.getResult().getNumber());
} catch (ConnectionException e) {
}
```

And it should give you the `COUNT` result, but I am querying my table with cql3 and it isn't giving me a "Number", but "Rows", only one Row and only one Column.

The method `hasNumber` gives `False` and the method `hasRows` gives `True`, so now, How can I get the Result of my `COUNT` query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
System.out.println("CQL Count: " + result.getResult().getRows().getRowByIndex(0).getColumns().getColumnByName("count").getLongValue());
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on abhi's answer but added a limit of 1M to bypass default limit of 10K.

```
private long getCount(ColumnFamily<String, String> columnFamily) throws ConnectionException {
    OperationResult<CqlResult<String, String>> result = context.getClient().prepareQuery(columnFamily)
            .withCql("SELECT count(*) FROM Standard1 limit 1000000;")
            .execute();

    return result.getResult().getRows().getRowByIndex(0).getColumns().getColumnByName("count").getLongValue();
}
```

Comment: yes, you can specify the limit, if not 10,000 is the default limit.